# How to manage AdMob behaviors on iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, admob

I've some questions about the AdMob behaviour on iOS.
there is a delegate method:

`-(void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error{`

An example:

1) I open my app, Internet Connection is OK, `adViewDidReceiveAd` is called.

2) Internet Connection is down, `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` is called.

I'd remove the ad when the view isn't showing an ad. But how to verify when no Ad is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didFailToReceiveAdWithError`: should be a good indication that an ad isn't being shown. If you want more info about why the ad specifically isn't being shown, you can check the type of `GADErrorCode` that comes back (take a look at `GADRequestError.h` for an explanation of the different error codes). You can probably safely hide the `GADBannerView` whenever `didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` is called.